# What's the math behind minmax/1fr?

Tags: javascript, css, minmax

How can I manually determine how many columns show up in my grid with these rules?

```
display: grid;
grid-column-gap: 1rem;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(260px, 1fr));
```

For example, in my project the container `<div>` is `1463px`. This results in 5 columns, each child having a width of `279.8px`. Knowing my container width and the `grid-template-columns` rule, how can I calculate number of columns?

Comment: Auto-fill FILLS the row with as many columns as it can fit based on the available width. https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/

Comment: You can get a rough idea based on "width / min" and take the integer. Unfortunately, the `gap` tends to complicate the issue but unless it's an extreme case, the integer should give you the number of columns expected.